# Combining a SharePoint list with a media web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, video

I'm trying to find a way to do something like this: there is a sharepoint list where I stored videos, or links to videos with all the necessary information, and then when I click on any of those list items it should play in the media web part. 
So I have a sinlge place holder for all the media videos which is connected in some way with the list of videos.

I tried to establish a connection between both parts, but the media web part does not accept a connection.

Any suggestion on how I can approach this problem?
Thanks,
Laura
[image: is it possible to combine a 'media web part' with a sharepoint list?]

Comment: Out of box its not possible. But you can do workaround for that. This link will give some idea: https://nikhildarjee.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/adding-media-web-part-dynamically/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed the following solution:
[image]

I hope this helps someone else!
Cheers,
Laura